# Use background worker and update the status

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I am triying to use background worker for my data which process 1k+ records and update them to the `excel sheet`. So I thought of using the background worker and the `background worker` gets hit but coming out of it and triggering the `background work completed` event without performing its action.

Below is my code:

```
    Private Sub btnExport_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExport.Click
            ProgressBar1.Maximum = 100
            ProgressBar1.Step = 1
            ProgressBar1.Value = 0
            BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True
            BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()       
        End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
                    If cmbAccounts.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
                        Dim Input1 As String = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "\Samples\abc.xlsx"
                        Dim tdate As String = Me.PresentDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

                        Using myConnection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=mydatasource;Initial Catalog=db0XXX;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=abcd"), myCommand As New SqlCommand("GetLog", myConnection), adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(myCommand)
                            myConnection.Open()
                            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountID", 123)


     myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", tdate)
                        ' Create the DataAdapter
                        Dim myDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(myCommand)

                        ' Create the DataSet
                        Dim myDataSet As New DataSet

                        ' Fill the DataSet
                        myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet)
                        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(0)
                        Me.DataGridView2.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(1)
                        Me.DataGridView3.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(2)

                        ' Close the connection
                        myConnection.Close()


                        Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
                        Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
                        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add

                        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Input1)
                        xlWorkBook.Sheets(1).activate()
                        xlApp.Cells.HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter
                        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
                        xlApp.Columns.ColumnWidth = 25


                        For i = 1 To myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count
                            For j = 0 To myDataSet.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
                                xlApp.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = _
                                    myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(i - 1)(j).ToString()
                            Next
                        Next
                        EndOfFirstTable = myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count + 1

                        Dim SecondTableFirstRow As Integer = EndOfFirstTable + 1
                        For i = 1 To myDataSet.Tables(1).Rows.Count
                            For j = 0 To myDataSet.Tables(1).Columns.Count - 1
                                xlApp.Cells(i + SecondTableFirstRow, j + 1) = _
                                    myDataSet.Tables(1).Rows(i - 1)(j).ToString()
                            Next
                        Next
                        EndOfSecondTable = myDataSet.Tables(1).Rows.Count + 1

                        Dim ThirdTableFirstRow As Integer = EndOfSecondTable + 1
                        For i = 1 To myDataSet.Tables(2).Rows.Count
                            For j = 0 To myDataSet.Tables(2).Columns.Count - 1
                                xlApp.Cells(i + ThirdTableFirstRow, j + 1) = _
                                    myDataSet.Tables(2).Rows(i - 1)(j).ToString()
                            Next
                        Next
                        EndOfThirdTable = myDataSet.Tables(2).Rows.Count + 1


                        If DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 + DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1 + DataGridView3.Rows.Count - 1 = 0 Then
                            For i = 1 To 2
                                For j = 0 To myDataSet.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
                                    xlApp.Cells(2, j + 1) = "NULL"
                                Next
                            Next
                        End If

                        xlApp.Columns.AutoFit()

                        Dim rSearchRange As Range
                        rSearchRange = xlWorkBook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns(1)

                        'for example
                        If xlApp.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(rSearchRange) Then
                            rSearchRange.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete()
                        End If

                        lblChargeEntry.Text = DataGridView1.RowCount - 1 + DataGridView2.RowCount - 1 + DataGridView3.RowCount - 1
                        value1 = lblChargeEntry.Text

                        Dim _
                            Destinationpath As String = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "\Output\abc_" & tdate & ".xlsx"
                        xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(Destinationpath)
                        '~~> Close the File
                        xlWorkBook.Close()
                        '~~> Quit the Excel Application
                        xlApp.Quit()
                    End Using


                    Using myConnection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=mydatasource;Initial Catalog=db0XXX;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=abcd"), myCommand As New SqlCommand("GetLog", myConnection), adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(myCommand)
                        Dim Input2 As String = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "\Samples\bbc.xls"
                        myConnection.Open()
                        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountID", 234)
                        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", tdate)
                        ' Create the DataAdapter
                        Dim myDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(myCommand)

                        ' Create the DataSet
                        Dim myDataSet As New DataSet

                        ' Fill the DataSet
                        myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet)
                        Me.DataGridView4.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(0)

                        ' Close the connection
                        myConnection.Close()


                        Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
                        Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
                        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add

                        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Input2)
                        xlWorkBook.Sheets(1).activate()
                        xlApp.Cells.HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter
                        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
                        xlApp.Columns.ColumnWidth = 25


                        Try
                            Dim EndOfFirstTable As Integer
                            For i = 1 To myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count
                                For j = 0 To myDataSet.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
                                    xlApp.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = _
                                        myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(i - 1)(j).ToString()
                                Next
                            Next
                            EndOfFirstTable = myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count + 1


                            If DataGridView4.Rows.Count - 1 = 0 Then
                                For i = 1 To 2
                                    For j = 0 To myDataSet.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
                                        xlApp.Cells(2, j + 1) = "NULL"
                                    Next
                                Next
                            End If

                            xlApp.Columns.AutoFit()
                        Catch
                        End Try

                        Dim rSearchRange As Range
                        rSearchRange = xlWorkBook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns(1)
                        'for example
                        If xlApp.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(rSearchRange) Then
                            rSearchRange.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete()
                        End If

                        lblPaymentPosting.Text = DataGridView4.RowCount - 1
                        value2 = lblPaymentPosting.Text

                        Dim _
                            Destinationpath As String = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & _
                                                        "\Output\bbc_" & tdate & ".xls"
                        xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(Destinationpath)
                        '~~> Close the File
                        xlWorkBook.Close()
                        '~~> Quit the Excel Application
                        xlApp.Quit()
                        cmbAccounts.SelectedIndex = 1
                    End Using
                End If

                If cmbAccounts.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
                    Dim Input3 As String = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "\Samples\123.xlsx"
                    Dim tdate As String = Me.PresentDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

                    Using myConnection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=mydatasource;Initial Catalog=db0XXX;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=abcd"), myCommand As New SqlCommand("GetLog", myConnection), adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(myCommand)
                        myConnection.Open()
                        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountID", 234)
                        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", tdate)
                        ' Create the DataAdapter
                        Dim myDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(myCommand)

                        ' Create the DataSet
                        Dim myDataSet As New DataSet

                        ' Fill the DataSet
                        myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet)
                        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(0)
                        Me.DataGridView2.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(1)
                        Me.DataGridView3.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(2)

                        ' Close the connection
                        myConnection.Close()



                        Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
                        Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
                        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add

                        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Input3)
                        xlWorkBook.Sheets(1).activate()
                        xlApp.Cells.HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter
                        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
                        xlApp.Columns.ColumnWidth = 25



                        For i = 1 To myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count
                            For j = 0 To myDataSet.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
                                xlApp.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = _
                                    myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(i - 1)(j).ToString()
                            Next
                        Next
                        EndOfFirstTable = myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count + 1

                        Dim SecondTableFirstRow As Integer = EndOfFirstTable + 1

                        For i = 1 To myDataSet.Tables(1).Rows.Count
                            For j = 0 To myDataSet.Tables(1).Columns.Count - 1
                                xlApp.Cells(i + SecondTableFirstRow, j + 1) = _
                                    myDataSet.Tables(1).Rows(i - 1)(j).ToString()
                            Next
                        Next
                        EndOfSecondTable = myDataSet.Tables(1).Rows.Count + 1

                        Dim ThirdTableFirstRow As Integer = EndOfSecondTable + 1
                        For i = 1 To myDataSet.Tables(2).Rows.Count
                            For j = 0 To myDataSet.Tables(2).Columns.Count - 1
                                xlApp.Cells(i + ThirdTableFirstRow, j + 1) = _
                                    myDataSet.Tables(2).Rows(i - 1)(j).ToString()
                            Next
                        Next

                        If DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 + DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1 + DataGridView3.Rows.Count - 1 = 0 Then
                            For i = 1 To 2
                                For j = 0 To myDataSet.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
                                    xlApp.Cells(2, j + 1) = "NULL"
                                Next
                            Next
                        End If

                        xlApp.Columns.AutoFit()


                        Dim rSearchRange As Range
                        rSearchRange = xlWorkBook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns(1) 'for example
                        If xlApp.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(rSearchRange) Then
                            rSearchRange.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete()
                        End If

                        lblChargeEntry.Text = DataGridView1.RowCount - 1 + DataGridView2.RowCount - 1 + DataGridView3.RowCount - 1
                        value3 = lblChargeEntry.Text
                        Dim Destinationpath As String = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "\Output\234_Log_" & tdate & ".xlsx"
                        xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(Destinationpath )
                        '~~> Close the File
                        xlWorkBook.Close()
                        '~~> Quit the Excel Application
                        xlApp.Quit()
                    End Using

    For j As Integer = 0 To 99999
        Caluculate(j)
        backgroundWorker.ReportProgress((j * 100) \ 100000)
    Next
End If
End Sub

    Private Sub Caluculate(i As Integer)
        Dim pow As Double = Math.Pow(i, i)
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs)
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
          MsgBox("Reports created succesfully!")
    End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it (using a simple breakpoint)?

Comment: Yes but it doesnt show me any error and just comes out of If statement and triggers the completed job...If I remove my code then it works fine with the progress bar status

Comment: Ok, you posted way to much code! for an issue with BackgroundWorker. Just put simple thread worker that writes to a single excel cell, then see if the problem is with the worker first.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a try/catch around the if statement. That won't address the problem but should let you see the exception. You're running into a cross-threading UI access issue when accessing the `ComboBox` from within the thread.

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5074467/264607

If you really want to access UI elements see here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.checkaccess.aspx

Comment: @BlackICE- I have tried it and that too didn't work and it dosent throw any kind of exceptions.

Comment: You've got a lot of UI access going on in the background worker, you're going to have to change that, you can't directly access the UI elements from a thread other than the UI thread.

Comment: You can pass the datagridview as object in the reportprogress (2:nd parameter). Do all the changes in the progresschanged event or in the completed events.