# Multithreading in vb.net to simulate task

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, foreach

I have a program that is doing one task.
For Example i have one list box containing some links.

And on the other hand my program is opening them one by one but i want it to be done faster
i have used for-each loop for that purpose.
All what i want to do is i wanna give every 2 or 3 link to a different thread or if there is any other solution to make it Faster Kindly tell me.
This is a small piece of code from my program.

```
For value As Integer = 1 To TextBox1.Text

        If (value = TextBox1.Text) Then
            Exit For

        End If
        Dim page As String = "-p-" & value

        Extractor.ScrapLinks(txturl.Text + page, lstbox)
        lbllinks.Text = lstbox.Items.Count

    Next
```

Comment: Something like a [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) loop?

Comment: `For value As Integer = 1 To TextBox1.Text` should give you compile errors.

Comment: nope it isn't giving because textbox has integer values

Comment: I've heard about BackGroundWorker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what Extractor.ScrapLinks actually do, but it seems that you need to access UI thread and you cannot create multiple UI threads so eventually you will process them sequentially

What you can do to improve the solution is to read the data you want from the UI controls and then process that data on a separate thread, after completion you can fill the results into the UI by invoking some method on the UI thread as shown below

```
Delegate Sub PerformOperationDel(value As Integer)
Sub PerformOperation(value As Integer)
    Dim page As String = "-p-" & value
    Extractor.ScrapLinks(txturl.Text + page, lstbox)
    lbllinks.Text = lstbox.Items.Count
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For value As Integer = 1 To CInt(TextBox1.Text) - 1
        lstbox.BeginInvoke(New PerformOperationDel(AddressOf PerformOperation))
    Next
End Sub
```

You can use backgroundworkers but notice that you cannot access UI controls in the DoWork but you can access them on work completed (Refer to: [Background worker proper way to access UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073511/background-worker-proper-way-to-access-ui))

Best of luck

Comment: @Ahmed , I've posted my whole code at 
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/62885/phone-number-extracting-using-regex-and-htmlagilitypack-in-vb-net#
You can check my whole code and give me feedback.

Comment: Do you still have any problems?